# How to go to the parent of an element in if

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I've got a little problem with this code:

```
if($(actualFilter + ' .select2-container ul .select2-search-choice div').html() === data) {
    $(this).parent() // and now I want to search for "a"
});
```

Is it possible to somehow set this code in `if` as this?

Because if I want to go up with `parent()` and then when I am in `.select2-search-choice` in this I want to search for `a` to do `click()`.

Comment: By "search for 'a' " do you mean you want to search for the next anchor tag and click on it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! you question is little unclear and is missing markup. If you are looking for ways to search `a` in parent, `$(this).parent().find('a')` should do the trick.

Comment: if (if === true) then I want to go up from ".select2-search-choice div" to ".select2-search-choice" because here is also "a" and I want to do "click()" on this "a"

Comment: @Rajesh but how can I achieve "this" when I am in if?

Comment: `this` will change context if function is changed. JS does not have block scope(except let is ES6)

Comment: @Rajesh yes I know :) I mean I want to set this = "$(actualFilter + ' .select2-container ul .select2-search-choice div'" from "if" statement

Comment: Why `this`? just set it to `var $ddl1 = $(actualFilter + ' .select2-container ul .select2-search-choice div')` and then `if($ddl1.html()=== data) $ddl1.parent().find("a:first").click()`

Comment: @Rajesh thanks it works! but I have weird problem :D "ul .select2-search-choice div" I have 2 li.select2-search-choice in this ul and now when I do this what you wrote it affects to both li not only for this where $ddli.html() === data)

Comment: @Rajesh that's why I wanted to use somehow "this" to affect this only for this one li where li div === data

Comment: @boroks In such case, you will have to navigate using `this` not update it. Also, without markup, its very difficult to give proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the jquery [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) functions.

```
if($(actualFilter + ' .select2-container ul .select2-search-choice div').html() === data) {
    $(this).parent().next("a").trigger( "click" );
});
```

Comment: but in this situation this !== "$(actualFilter + ' .select2-container ul .select2-search-choice div'"

Answer (score 0):

`this` or `$(this)` is available in events like

```
$('div').click(function(){
     alert(this.tageName); //will print DIV for you
});
```

In if statement you have to simply reuse the selector like

```
var yourElement = $(actualFilter + '.select2-container ul .select2-search-choice div');
if(yourElement.html() === data) {
    var parentEl = yourElement.parent();
});
```